# Are there any iOS apps that let third-party developers extend functionality?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

If so, can you give examples? What I'm looking for is any apps that let third-parties write code or modules/"mini apps" for extended functionality that a user can install/execute from within the app.

Comment: While you might be able to build a proprietary in-house app for *enterprise distribution* that does what you suggest, it's unlikely Apple would approve such an app for distribution to consumers via the App Store.  Check the guidelines.  That being said, if you are still interested in a counterexample, you might want to edit your question to be specific to the App Store, if that was its intent.

Comment: From a more technical standpoint, consider [this question at Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733847/can-you-build-dynamic-libraries-for-ios-and-load-them-at-runtime).

Comment: I'm not sure the purpose of this question, but Chris is right: Apple would be very unlikely to accept such an app — it may even be explicitly against the app store guidelines. However, there are apps that let you run code snippets (rather, run them on an external sever and view the output).

Comment: jtbandes - the point was that I am interested in making such an app and was curious if there were examples that I can reference. If you meant why would someone want such an app, well, lots of great applications or web products let the community create "extensions" to add new functionality. For example with Facebook, and how Facebook has apps (although not sure if Facebook apps run on the mobile iOS app).

Answer (score 1):

Nope. As a developer, I know this is not possible unless the "child" app is installed as an app, supports a URL scheme, the "parent" app knows about, and their interaction can be limited to launching each-other back and forth.

Note: the situation with jailbroken devices and in house applications is different, but I assume you don't care about those.

Answer (score 0):

Tongbu App Store. It may be one of the best ones but it may have some problems.
It crashes some times but can easily be fixed by connecting to computer.